# Change click to keypress in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard-shortcuts

I have downloaded a `HTML5` audio player source from [here](http://%20https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-audio-player-with-playlist/)
and I want to change the way the player is controlled from clicking to key pressing.

In `js` file I found this:

```
// play click
    $('.play').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        playAudio();
    });
```

and I tried to implement this but didn't work:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 78) {
    e.preventDefault();

        playAudio();
    }};
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 78) {
           e.preventDefault();
           playAudio();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No tested but you can try this

```
document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  //rest of the code
};
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code to

```
$('.play').keydown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    playAudio();
});
```

this will work

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", yourFunction, false); //listen to any keydown

function yourFunction(e)
{
 if (e.keyCode == "65") 
 {
   alert("The 'a' key is pressed.");
 }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `.onkeypress`.

Assuming that `playAudio`, you can emulate what the jQuery is doing as follows:

```
var elements=document.querySelectorAll('.play');
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) elements[i].onkeypress=function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode!=78) return;
    playAudio();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

If you’re sure there will only be one such element, you can write:

```
document.querySelector.onkeypress=function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode!=78) return;
    playAudio();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working demo for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/milanchheda/b478atu0/1/

HTML:

```
 <div class="containerClass">
  <input type="text" class="inputClass" />
</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
 $(".containerClass").on('keydown', '.inputClass', function() {
  alert("keydown...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you everybody. i appreciate all your help. my implementation works well after i clear the browser cookies.